# Como carregar um array e dividir as posições do mesmo por caracter especial

Tags: javascript, jquery, devexpress

Tenho uma tabela onde existem filtros para a mesma:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como podem ver na imagem, para cada coluna tenho um filtro onde utilizador pode digitar o que entender para fazer a pesquisa que entender. Agora estou a permitir que o utilizador faça download da listagem em formato PDF com os filtros aplicados. Então, estou a criar um array com os filtros onde depois envio o mesmo array para uma função num controller da aplicação. Até ai tudo bem!

**Problema:**

Caso o utilizador num filtro escreva por exemplo `Belém, Lda`, e como existe uma virgula neste filtro, vou criar mais uma posição no array e não criar uma string completa numa posição do array.

O que estou a pensar fazer é: dividir cada posição no array com um carácter que o utilizador não utilize, como por exemplo um `☺` (smile)

**Dúvida:**

Para ir buscar os dados dos filtros estou a usar (uso componente do [DevExpress](http://demos.devexpress.com/MVCxGridViewDemos/Editing/BatchEditing) onde disponibilizam funções javascript para poder manipular dados, neste caso o `filterEditorState` para ir buscar os dados dos filtros):

`var myArray = gvSortingListagemGARs.filterEditorState; //Devolve um array com todos os filtros`

Eu sei que posso construir o array da seguinte forma:

```
var pos1 = gvSortingListagemGARs.filterEditorState[1];
var pos2 = gvSortingListagemGARs.filterEditorState[2];
var pos3 = gvSortingListagemGARs.filterEditorState[3];
...
```

E depois junto todos os dados num array, colocando sempre com um `☺` no inicio e no fim de cada string.

**É possível construir logo um array e alterar o divisor de posição (virgula)?** Assim evitava de fazer N linhas e simplificar o meu código.

Comment: Em relação ao "smile" acho melhor ter uma string tipo password. Ainda não compreendi bem o problema. Quer mudar a array que recebe em `var myArray = gvSortingListagemGARs.filterEditorState;` ou encontrar uma alternativa para gerar a array?

Comment: Queria encontrar uma alternativa ao gerar o array. Onde pudesse contornar a questão da virgula na string de um filtro. A solução que pensei foi ir buscar filtro a filtro a string respetiva, mas ai me questionei se existe outra solução para resolver isto

Comment: Mas mesmo com sub-arrays e caso use o split, uma string de pesquisa pode ficar comprometida (por exemplo `Belém, Lda`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma possibilidade é ir ao DOM buscar esses valores e criar uma array com eles. Usando o JSON.stringify dá para passar para o lado do servidor em formato JSON e aí as virgulas dentro de cada string são mantidas.

```
var array = $('table tr:first td').map(function () {
    return $(this).text(); 
}).get(); 
var JSONarray = JSON.stringify(array);
```

Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/XT4N6/

Notas:

- talvez queiras usar `return $(this).find('input').val();` se esses campos forem inputs
- uso o `.get()` para obter uma array nativa, e não um objeto "array-like" do jQuery